# Mechanisms For Avoidance of Race Condition

Tags: race-condition

what are various mechanisms adopted to avoid race condition? well there is critical section problem!Any mechanisms besides that?

Comment: Can you narrow down your question?  Have you searched the site for an answer before posting?

Comment: I could find out what exactly a "race condition" is,but mechanisms for avoidance is not specified clearly @TimBiegeleisen